# Fit the text into image PHP GD

Tags: php

Helllo, Using GD I'm creating a png image from a $text. The $text is script generated and may take a few lines. 
So, here is my code:

```
$imageWidth=400;
$imageHeight=100;
$logoimg = imagecreatetruecolor($imageWidth, $imageHeight); //create Image

imagealphablending($logoimg, false);
imagesavealpha($logoimg, true);
$col=imagecolorallocatealpha($logoimg,255,255,255,127);
imagefill($logoimg, 0, 0, $col);

$white = imagecolorallocate($logoimg, 0, 0, 0);
$font = "TNR.ttf"; //font path
$fontsize=14;
$x=10;
$y=20;
$angle=0;
imagettftext($logoimg, $fontsize,$angle , $x, $y, $white, $font, $text);

$target="temp.png"; //path of target
imagepng($logoimg,$target);
```

My problem is that sometimes the text goes cropped by a few pixels. Here is an example:

[image: cropped text]

So, the question is, how can I make the text fit the image? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use imagettfbox function to check edges before writing the text:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php
Or, perhaps, add a border around text.